# Make attributes mass assignable only during creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is it possible to have an attribute that is only mass-assignable during the creation of a model object?

For example, the `username` attribute should be mass-assignable when creating the object, but not after that (it should be read-only).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what `attr_readonly` does:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :username
end

u = User.create(:username => 'dude')
u.username # => 'dude'

u.update_attributes(:username => 'dudette')
u.reload.username # => 'dude'
```