# Rails attr_readonly doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376659/make-attributes-mass-assignable-only-during-creation/7376686) and the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ReadonlyAttributes/ClassMethods/attr_readonly) of `attr_readonly` the following should be possible:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :foo
  attr_readonly :bar
end

m = MyModel.create(foo: '123', bar: 'bar') # Should work
m.update_attributes(bar: 'baz')            # Should not work
```

However the first one fails, saying that I can't mass-assign `bar`. What am I mising?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment)

> `attr_accessible` takes a list of attributes that will be accessible.
>   **All other attributes will be protected**.

So `attr_accessible` made `bar` attribute as protected from mass-assignment.

Comment: I see, so I have to add it to both, `attr_accessible` and `attr_readlony`? Kind of counter-intuitive...

Comment: No, of you want to mass-asign it, it won't be a readonly. You have to do only attr_accessible.

Comment: But if I only want to mass-assign it once on creation?

Answer (score 2):

You can make the attribute , suppose ,key as:-

```
attr_accessible :key
```

and then add one more validation

```
validate :check_if_key_changed, :on=> :update

private
def check_if_key_changed
  if self.key_changed?
    errors.add(:key,"cant change key")
  end
end
```

In this way you will be able to  mass-assign it once on creation and can also make sure that it do not get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Before Rails 7.1 `attr_accessible` prevented the change from being persisted on the database, but it allowed the change to be made and kept in memory:

```rb
class Dashboard < ApplicationRecord
  attr_readonly :name
end
```

```bash
d = Dashboard.create(name: "INITIAL NAME")
d.update(name: "ANOTHER NAME")
d.name #=> "ANOTHER NAME"
d.reload && d.name #=> "INITIAL NAME"
```

Since Rails 7.1 an error will be raised if we try to update a persisted readonly attributed. (However please check your app configuration `active_record.raise_on_assign_to_attr_readonly`)