# Rails -- auto generate read only attribute on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a class with a read-only attribute:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :key
  validates_uniqueness_of :key
end
```

I would like to auto-generate the `:key` attribute when the object is created and never let the attribute be changed after creation.  I tried this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_readonly :key
  validates_uniqueness_of :key

  before_create :generate_key

  private
    def generate_key
      self.key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Time.now.to_s + rand(100000).to_s)[0..5]
    end
end
```

And that predictably results in an error since I'm trying to assign the protected attribute.  What's the appropriate way to do this?

Comment: Can you try `self[:key] = [...]` instead?

Comment: Can you try to do `before_validation_on_create :generate_key` instead of `before_create :generate_key`. Since validations are checked before creation (so, before the generate_key), it can cause some troubles.

Comment: It that your full model definition? I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383061/rails-attr-readonly-doesnt-work and was wondering if that was the situation you're in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the key as:-

```
attr_accessible :key
```

and then add one more validation

```
validate :check_if_key_changed, :on=> :update
validates_uniqueness_of :key
before_create :generate_key

private
  def generate_key
    self.key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Time.now.to_s + rand(100000).to_s)[0..5]
  end

def check_if_key_changed
  if self.key_changed?
    errors.add(:key,"cant change key")
  end
end
```

In this way you will be able to generate key and can also make sure that it do not get updated.

Comment: Yep, this definitely works.  I'm surprised Rails doesn't already have a solution for this problem.  It seems like it would be fairly common.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
def generate_key
  self[:key] = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Time.now.to_s + rand(100000).to_s)[0..5]
end
```

or:

```
def generate_key
  self.write_attribute :key, Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Time.now.to_s + rand(100000).to_s)[0..5]
end
```