# Is there a better way to create read-only attributes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I'm creating an ActiveRecord object in Rails that I want to have read-only attributes. I initially tried using `attr_readonly` but was dismayed to find that it:

1. [Disabled mass-updating of those properties, even on new records](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11383135/1176156)
2. Did not raise an exception if the record was saved, or notify you that a read-only property was being changed in any way.

I want both of these features; this is my attempt at an implementation:

```
# For use with ActiveRecord

module ReadOnlyAttributes

  class ReadOnlyAttributeException < StandardError
  end

  def create_or_update # Private, but its what every method gets funneled through.
    if !self.new_record? && self.respond_to?(:read_only_attributes)
      changed_symbols = self.changed.map(&:to_sym)
      if changed_symbols.intersect?(self.read_only_attributes)
        raise ReadOnlyAttributeException, "Readonly attributes modified on #{self.class}: #{changed_symbols & self.read_only_attributes}"
      end
    end

    super
  end

end
```

And then in my model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  include ReadOnlyAttributes

  def read_only_attributes
    [:event_type]
  end

end
```

Is there a built-in or better way to get read-only properties that meet the above requirements?

I'm still pretty new to Ruby/Rails, so I would also appreciate any stylistic comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base    
  before_save :protect_attributes

  private
  def protect_attributes
     false if !new_record? && event_type_changed?
  end
end
```

Another thought is, why bother enforcing this at the model level? What is the difference between a read-only attribute and an attribute that can only be written to in the create action of your controller? You could always do this:

```
class EventController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    @event = Event.new params.require(:event).permit :event_name, :event_type
  end

  def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id]).update params.require(:event).permit(:event_name)
  end
end
```

Comment: That works great, thanks! This particular object is used for internal record keeping, and doesn't have a public facing controller.

Comment: Glad I could help. Another, slightly better, approach would be to use a custom validator.

Comment: Best not to enforce in the controller because you might use another way to CRUD the model, e.g. a rake task or console.