# How to record the IP address a user signed up with using Devise and Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I tried the following:

In `user.rb`:

```
before_create :record_sign_up_ip

protected
def record_sign_up_ip
  self.sign_up_ip = current_sign_in_ip
end
```

Unfortunately, although `current_sign_in_ip` has my correct local ip of `127.0.0.1`, `sign_up_ip` remains as `nil`. How can I easily get the IP of someone signing up? Normally I would put this in the `create` controller, but with Devise, there is no controller for `User`.

Comment: You can override/supplement the controller used by Devise as noted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the controller used by Devise as noted at [Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)

As modified from that post, create app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:

```
# app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    params['user']['sign_up_ip'] = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']   
    super
  end

end
```

Also modified from that post, to use that controller:

```
# app/config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "users/registrations"}
```

You also need to make sign_up_up accessible (for Rails 3):

```
# app/models/user.rb
  attr_accessible :sign_up_ip
```

Comment: I don't want `sign_up_ip` to be mass assignable. Any way to modify the `User` object before it gets saved?

Comment: In that case, I would probably copy over the entire create method that you are overriding from Devise::RegistrationsController at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb and modify it to manually add the IP address without making sign_up_ip mass assignable.

Comment: Another option would be to use attr_readonly -- that way, the field will be able to be assigned when the record is created, but mass assignment will not be permitted to change the value.  Since the code above sets sign_up_ip when the record is created, it will not be possible to change it.  I think this is a better option, and have edited my answer to change attr_accessible to attr_readonly.

Comment: Nevermind about attr_readonly -- it appears that attr_readonly does not work in conjunction with other fields defined as attr_accessible -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383061/rails-attr-readonly-doesnt-work  However, that post also shows how to prevent changes to the sign_up_ip by implementing a validation that only runs on update.

Answer (score 0):

In your user model,

```
def init
    self.sign_up_ip = current_sign_in_ip
end
```

Comment: When I tried that, init does not seem to be called during User creation.  Is there additional configuration required?