# Devise gem and User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Devise's examples and tutorials say me to have something like this in User model:

```
attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
```

So I have two questions about this.

1. Why should I make "name" and "password" accessible? I want them to be protected, does devise let me change this?
2. What on earth do fields like "password_confirmation" and "remember_me" do in user model? Now I can write something like `User.find(1).password_confirmation`, it works but has no sense at all.

How to deal with that?

Comment: 2 cents: about `password_confirmation`, you are right to feel odd - code smell in a way - it is not a concern of the domain; but its *easy* so we do it. About `remember_me` - IMO it is part of the domain - as far as the `User` being use for purpose of kind-of-like-you-know,authentication, is concerned.

Comment: Devise does not bother or enforce anything on your model - you decide what you want in it. Goes for `attr_accessible` too. IMO, fields that are "sensitive" like say an "is_admin" or "paid_for_subscription" etc. attributes, must not be mass-assignable. The password field is really just any other data *for that user*, so mass-assignment is okay in the context of the user. Of course, you don't want some other user modifying another users' data, but that is not what `attr_accessible` is designed to prevent - that's protection up to you (think "scoping").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found an answer.

1. Devise uses mass-assignment, and there is nothing you can do about that. There is a Github issue about that: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/718. I'm working on idea how we can change Devise to avoid it relying on mass-assignment. I will be happy to know your opinion.
2. As long as Devise takes away your right to define our attr-accessible list, there are two things you can do about that:

   a. You can just use `attr_readonly` along with `attr_accessible`. It will open door for Devise, but not for your other forms, read [Make attributes mass assignable only during creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376659/make-attributes-mass-assignable-only-during-creation)

   b. `def mass_assignment_authorizer` allows you to define dynamic attr-accessible list, read http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible?view=asciicast. IMHO, this way is overkill for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need all four of these fields accessible in order to create the login and sign up forms. You don't have to worry about the password fields in the database, they are just virtual attributes. The actual fields in the database, which you can confirm in the schema, are actually the encrypted_password and salt. It is actually a very functional, proven and secure system. You should focus innovating in the rest of your app and let devise do its work for you, which it does very well.

Comment: I don't want "name" field to be mass-assignable (it's me to decide, not Devise, isn't it?) and I don't want garbage like "password_confirmation" to be in User model (it's not part of the model, it's just part of the registration form).