# Save Rails model from controller params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

I tried User.create(params), but this says that "controller" and "action" aren't mass assignable. I could exclude these properties, but is there an easier way to marshall to the properties I need?

Some examples seem to indicate I can use params[:user], but if I want the post to be just the user object, params[:user] looks like it's nil.

So I'm posting with {username: 'blah', password: 'blah'}, and username and password are in the params, but not params[:user].

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.create(params[:user])
    if user.save
      render :json => user, :status => :created
    else
      logger.error user.errors
      render :json => {:status => :error, :errors => user.errors}, :status => :bad_request
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376659/make-attributes-mass-assignable-only-during-creation

Comment: This is not even remotely the same question.

Comment: if you do a simple output of `params` you'll see it has different params like `controller` and `action`. `User.create(params)` will try to create a User and assign the params attributes to it. As your params has non-attribute values (action, controller, commit, utf, etc), it wont work and raise a Mass Assignment error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `User.create(request.request_parameters)` or `User.create(JSON.parse(request.body.read))`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a convention in Rails projects, where form elements are named in a certain way (using the form helpers does this for you automatically):

```
<input type='text' name='user[username]'>
<input type='text' name='user[username]'>
```

When they are posted to the controller, these are converted to the params hash:

```
params = {
  :user => {
    :username => 'whatever',
    :password => 'somepass'
  }
}
```

Because of the way the routing works, key-value pairs for the controller, action, id (if applicable) or any custom route parts are added to this params hash.

```
params.merge!({
  :controller => 'users',
  :action     => 'create'
})
```

If `params[:user]` is nil for you, you may need to change your form to match the convention.